# Why won't my Android app respond to Location events?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an Android application and I'm playing around with the LocationManager, right now just trying to get some basic functionality going. The problem is that when I send it a Location event, either through DDMS (Eclipse) or by telnet-ing to the emulator and using "geo", I'm not getting any response. I have my code below, can anyone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
public class HelloLocation extends Activity {
Toast mToast;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(HelloLocation.this, HelloLocationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(HelloLocation.this, 0, intent, 0);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.addProximityAlert(40.000, -74.000, 2500, -1, sender);   


        if(mToast != null) {
             mToast.cancel();
        }
        mToast = Toast.makeText(HelloLocation.this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        mToast.show();
    }
}
```

and my class that's supposed to respond to the Location event:

```
public class HelloLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm set off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register a receiver and define an intent filter, try this:

```
public class HelloLocation extends Activity {
   Toast mToast;
   // ADD LINE BELOW
   private static final String PROXIMITY_ALERT_INTENT = "AnythingYouLike";
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      // DELETE LINE BELOW
      //Intent intent = new Intent(HelloLocation.this, HelloLocationReceiver.class);
      // REPLACE WITH LINE BELOW
      Intent intent = new Intent(PROXIMITY_ALERT_INTENT);

      PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(HelloLocation.this, 0, intent, 0);

      LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
      lm.addProximityAlert(40.000, -74.000, 2500, -1, sender);   

      // ADD TWO LINES BELOW
      IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROXIMITY_ALERT_INTENT);
      registerReceiver(new HelloLocationReceiver(), filter);
      // ------------------------

      if(mToast != null) {
         mToast.cancel();
      }
      mToast = Toast.makeText(HelloLocation.this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
           mToast.show();
  }

}
```

It works for me.

Comment: Thanks so much... Just to clarify for me, the PROXIMITY_ALERT_INTENT field is just there to be an identifier for the Intent, right?

Comment: As far as I know that's correct. I tried having the filter as null and it didn't work.